# Gerund & participle: "She stormed out, 'slamming' the door so hard that the mirror fell off the wall"

Tags: verbs, gerunds, present-participles

> She stormed out, **slamming** the door so hard that the mirror fell off the wall.

As fa as I know, in Italian language **slamming** functions as a  gerund there, but, very often—as it could be the case here—there is no parallelism between English and Italian when one compares gerund and participle forms.

So the question is: how can one figure out if in the above example "slamming" is a gerund or a participle?

Comment: Why does it matter what label you affix to an *-ing* word?  It does its job perfectly well no matter how sweet smelleth the rose by any other name.

Comment: Yes @tchrist, but a rose must remain with the sun and the rain or its lovely promise won't come true.

Comment: Untrue! *Stat rosa pristina nomine, nomina nuda tenemus.*

Comment: @tchrist, may be; but don't forget _Non sum propheta et non sum filius prophetae_.

Comment: As side note, what in Italian is called _gerundio_, it is not called _gerund_ in English. A gerund is a form derived from a verb that functions as a noun; that definition matches what in Italian is defined as _participio_ ("forma nominale del verbo, usata generalmente con valore di aggettivo o di sostantivo").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In English the grammatical term *gerund* is used only for an *-ING* form which is employed as a noun. When an *-ING* form is used as an adjective or as a component of *progressive* verb construction it is called a *participle*.

Consequently, the way to tell what you should call a specific instance of an *-ING* form is to determine what role it plays in the sentence.

In the case at hand, *slamming ...* is a clause which describes what the subject *she* did. It is not the subject or object of another verb, it is not marked with a determiner or any other adjective. It has to be a participle.

In the same context you might use *slamming* as a gerund this way:

> She stormed out; slamming the door so hard that the mirror fell off the wall was her final comment on the discussion.

In this case, *slamming ... * is the subject of the verb *was*; *slamming* is a gerund.

It is usually pretty easy to figure out whether an *-ING* form is a participle or a gerund; but there is one tricky sort of construction. These require a subtler analysis.

> ***running*** water
>   ***running*** shoes

In both of these, *running* is used to modify the following noun; but in the first, *running* is a participle, while in the second it is a gerund.

This may be easier to understand if I introduce a new technical term. The *-ING* form is traditionally called the *present participle*, to distinguish it from the *past participle*, the *-ED* form; but it is just as proper, and sometimes more useful to call it an ***active participle***: a form which designates what the noun it modifies does, as opposed to the *passive participle*, which designates what is done to the noun it modifies.

So to discern whether an *-ING* form is a participle or a gerund you must ask yourself whether the action the form names is performed by the noun which it modifies.

- In *running water* it is in fact the water which runs, so *running* is a participle
- in *running shoes*, however, the shoes do not run; rather, they are used *for* running, just as *tennis shoes* are used for playing tennis or *football* shoes are used for playing soccer. In this case, *running* is a verb used as a noun—a gerund—which in turn is used attributively, as an adjective.

Isn’t English fun?!

Comment: I’ve never understood why we don’t just call them all *-ING* forms and be done with it.

Comment: @tchrist Yah: -Ø, -S, -D, -D2, -ING about sums it up, except for BE (-ØØ), AM(-Ø1), WAS(-DS).