# Is this -ing form a gerund or a participle?

Tags: adjectives, gerunds, participles

> Education is ***enlightening.***

In this example, is *enlightening* a gerund or a participle?

From my point of view (which can be wrong), *enlightening* is a gerund. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: related: **1.** [“Trying to be happy.”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106798/trying-to-be-happy) **2.** [Gerund & participle: “She stormed out, 'slamming' the door...](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/gerund-participle-she-stormed-out-slamming-the-door-so-hard-that-the-mirr) **3.** [“The man standing …” a gerund or an adjective?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/the-man-standing-a-gerund-or-an-adjective) **4.** [The role of 'sleeping' in 'sleeping baby'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95390/the-role-of-sleeping-in-sleeping-baby)

Comment: **5.** [Is “running” a gerund here?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71746/is-running-a-gerund-here) **6.** [The ambiguous “he is buried”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/the-ambiguous-he-is-buried) **7.** [Verbs which are always followed by past participle](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79014/verbs-which-are-always-followed-by-past-participle)

Answer (score 25):

In your sentence, *enlightening* is something called a **participial adjective**.  It is not a participle, which is a verb form; rather, it is an adjective derived from a participle.

We can show that *enlightening* is an adjective in your example using a *very*-test:

> Education is **very** enlightening.

We can modify gradable adjectives with *very*, but not verbs:

> *The water is **very** running. ← *ungrammatical*

In this example, *running* is a verb form, so it can't be modified by *very*.

---

In a different sentence, *enlightening* could be a participle:

> With funds from Congress, ShareSpace is gradually **enlightening** the public.

This is clearly a verb form.  It takes a direct object (*the public*), something adjectives generally don't do.  It also takes adverbial modification (*gradually*) but cannot be modified by *very*:

> *ShareSpace is **very** enlightening the public. ← *ungrammatical*

Most of the time, if *enlightening* is used as a verb form, it has a direct object.  Your example has no direct object, which tells us that it's probably an adjective form instead.

---

In another sentence, *enlightening* could be a gerund:

> By investigating and reporting on the many corrupt activities in the St. Louis area, the paper performs an essential role of **enlightening** the public.

In this example, the subordinate clause *enlightening the public* contains the verb form *enlightening*.  We can tell it's a verb form because it takes a direct object.  It cannot be modified with *very*, and it is not an adjective; but it also can't take a determiner, can't be modified by an adjective, and doesn't take noun-like complementation (*of the public*), so it's not a noun, either.  It's a gerund, a verb which heads a subordinate clause that is functionally similar to a noun phrase.

Because they're functionally similar to noun phrases, people often claim that gerunds *are* nouns.  They're not, though.  How can we tell?

---

Let's look at another example.

> He was expelled for wantonly **killing** the birds.

In this example, *killing* is a verb form, head of the subordinate clause *wantonly killing the birds*.  Because this clause is functionally similar to a noun phrase, some people might be tempted to call *killing* a noun here.  But it's clearly not:

1. *Killing* cannot be inflected like a noun.  If we change *killing* to *killings*, the sentence becomes ungrammatical.
2. *Killing* takes a direct object.  Verbs do that.  Nouns don't.
3. *Killing* does not take a determiner.  Adding *the* makes this sentence ungrammatical.
4. *Killing* takes an adverb (*wantonly*) as a modifier.  It does not take an adjective as a modifier.

*Wantonly killing the birds* has the form of a clause headed by a verb, not a noun phrase.  It is a mistake to say a gerund is a noun simply because the clause it appears in is functionally similar to a noun phrase.

We can derive an actual noun from *killing*, if we want to.  Let's do that:

> He was expelled for the wanton **killing** of the birds.

In this example *killing* is a gerundial noun, a noun derived from a gerund.  How can we tell?

1. *Killing* can be inflected like a noun.  If we change *killing* to *killings*, the sentence is still grammatical.
2. *Killing* takes an *of*-phrase as a complement instead of a direct object.  This is often the case with gerundial nouns derived from transitive gerunds, because nouns cannot take direct objects themselves.
3. *Killing* does take a determiner, *the*.  Verbs don't do that.
4. *Killing* takes an adjective (*wanton*) as a modifier.  It does not take an adverb as a modifier.

So we can see a clear difference between a gerund, which is a verb form, and a gerundial noun, which is a noun form.

---

It's true that an *-ing* form can be a gerund or participle (if we choose to make this distinction), but in your case it is neither.  It can also be a derived adjective, a derived noun, or a derived preposition (like *during* or *notwithstanding*).  As we saw earlier, in your example it is an adjective derived from a participle.

For more information, see *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, starting on page 81 (verbs vs. nouns), page 536 (verbs vs. adjectives), and page 610 (verbs vs. prepositions).

Comment: +1 Excellent post! Would be even excellenterer, perhaps, if you used *gerund-participle* instead of both *gerund* and *participle*  ... (- which I think tends to confuse leaners).

Comment: ... or even learners, as well as leaners ...

Comment: See also [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/366906/2085).

Answer (score 3):

In this case "enlightening" is a simple adjective derived from "enlighten", i.e. "something that enlightens".  So it's a participle that modifies "education".

A gerund is a noun derived from a verb, for example, "I enjoy swimming, but she enjoys sailing," or, "Running is a good form of exercise but it can be hard on the knees."

Because "enlighten" already has a related noun ("enlightenment"), "enlightening" is not normally a gerund.

Comment: Yes, it's an adjective. But if it's an adjective, it's not a participle; participles are verb forms. *Enlightening* here is a predicate adjective; predicates don't modify, they predicate. A gerund is not a noun, but is a verb form used in a subordinate clause which is functionally similar to a noun; see my answer.