# "Trying to be happy."

Tags: difference, gerunds, present-participles

So if this stands by itself is "Trying" a gerund or a participle. So in my opinion there are two ways to go about this. It could definitely be a gerund (*Trying* to be happy is always good) but I want to know if it being a participle where the agent is omitted is also possible. (It would be a progressive tense be + -ing form)

Imagine something like:

> Person A "What are you doing?"
>   Person B "(I am) trying to be funny"

as a short answer which is still sufficient in conveying the intended meaning. Maybe I am completely mistaken here and it probably doesn't even matter if it's a gerund or a participle but I like to truly understand the things I see and say so I hope someone can make sense of this.

Comment: Hello, may I ask if my answer proved helpful? Is there anything I missed out?

Answer (score 1):

**Present participles** are formed from verbs, and are often used to form verb tenses or adjectives. They can be used with an auxiliary to form the present continuous tense: *“We are dancing”* or used as an adjective, “My daughter bought some *dancing shoes”.* The present participle is used to *describe* the type of shoes, the shoes themselves are not dancing. This type of participial is commonly called a *[participial adjective](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html)*.

When the participle is used as a noun, it is called a **gerund**, e.g. *“She loves dancing”* and *“Dancing is one of the best forms of exercise.”*

Here the participle is used as the subject of a sentence, it is acting like a noun.

> **Trying** to make head or tails of this newfangled smartphone is crazy

It implies that *anyone* who tries to understand how to use that smartphone will fail in the process.

The verb in the next example is in the **present participle**, the subject is *she*

> She is **trying** to figure out a problem

For more details on the *[gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)* and the [participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) see Wikipedia.

To answer your question, `I want to know if it being a participle where the agent is omitted is also possible.`

> Person A "What are you doing?"
>   Person B "(I am) trying to be funny"

In this context, it's clear that the present participle is being used as a **verb**.