# The ambiguous "he is buried"

Tags: ambiguity, past-participles, parts-of-speech, participial-adjectives

In a sentence taken from the Oxford Dictionary:

> ‘The inscription on his tombstone in Groombridge Church, where **he is buried** alongside his three children, bears his original name and no reference to his nom de plume.’

Is ‘buried’ an adjective, a [participial adjective](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html), or a [predicate nominative](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-105-Predicate-Nominative.htm)  because it follows the copular verb *is*?

> **Predicate nominatives** complete only linking verbs. The linking verbs include the following: the helping verbs is: *am*, *are*, *was*, *were*, *be*, *being*, and *been*; the sense verbs: *look, taste, smell, feel, and sound*; and verbs like *become*, *seem*, *appear*, *grow*, *continue*, *stay*, and *turn*.

Or is it a past participle because the clause is in the passive voice?

Does “he is buried” mean *currently* his body lies in a coffin covered with soil, or  does it mean *he has been buried by someone*?

If we say **‘he was buried**’ it clearly refers to an event that happened and ended sometime in the past. It might even suggest that the burial ground has since been changed.

Comment: If they meant "he has been buried by someone", they would have written "he was buried" rather than "is". So they do mean his body is currently lying there.

Comment: @MrLister no worries, we are all here to learn! I have asked this question because when I told someone that I believed *buried* in "he is buried" was an adjective,  I was informed that it is in the present simple passive voice. I see if I can *dig  it up* (get it?!) somewhere.

Comment: I think asking whether "the clause is in the passive voice" or not could be tricky/ambiguous. FWIW, this sentence is an example of what's called "concealed passives": *The article needs checking.* (Because a *by*-phrase is permissible, e.g., *The article needs checking by the editor.*)

Comment: I don't believe he buried himself, whichever label you stick on the word.

Comment: Yikes! I hope I didn't really _inform_ you! I'll try to sound less authoritative, especially since I didn't think that comment through. "He is buried" is surely a copular sentence and _buried_ is adjectival. That's what I get for trying to be creative with the old chestnut _He died and was buried._ The point, though, was that clauses, not sentences, have voice and "tense".

Comment: @P.E.Dant but  *is* it passive, or *could* it be passive? Bit of a difference there.

Comment: It ain't passive and can't be. It's a copular sentence with the main clause in the active voice, obviously, since the copula can't have a passive voice. You can't _be been._

Comment: @P.E.Dant but you've just said now that the clause "he is buried" is in the passive voice. And to me you said ""He died, and is buried here."  `In that sentence, the first clause is in simple past and active voice, and the second in the simple present and the passive voice. This sentence is often used to demonstrate that a sentence cannot have voice and tense; only a clause can have these properties`

Comment: See my comment below Colin's very astute and concise answer. _He died, and is eaten by scavengers_ better illustrates the point.

Comment: But I also found an old grammar excerpt which clearly stated that the clause is in the passive voice. When I said  that *buried* looked like an adjective, you never confirmed. Hey, my knowledge of grammar is basic, better than your ordinary Joe, but next to nothing compared to linguists and professors, so I'm happy to be corrected over most things. And BTW I left the question as neutral as possible.

Comment: And it's a fine and interesting question and of value to learners. +1 ... There _are_ old grammars that might try to justify calling it a passive construction, but the modern grammars are much more useful and descriptive of how language _really_ works, not how it's _mandated_ to work. (Votes are not something you should bother with. An integer conveys no more information than a fart.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no ambiguity. 
In a present-tense narrative, it could be passive "He marries, he dies, he is buried" but in any other context, it is adjectival.

> He is buried

is a copular sentence, where "buried", an adjective, is the complement of the copula "is". You can call it a *participial adjective* if you like, as it originates as a participle: I'm not sure what the value is in doing so.

Whether or not you call it a *predicate nominative* depends on what you mean by "nominative", which the writer of the page you linked to didn't specify. Again, I don't know what advantage there is in such a designation.

Comment: The question has its genesis in the sentence _He died and was buried_ which is sometimes used to demonstrate that clauses, not sentences, have voice. I then expanded to _He died, and is buried here_ in a failed attempt to make the same case for tense in a single sentence. I'll have to try _He died, and is eaten by scavengers._ (Or is that a flop, as well?)

Comment: @P.E.Dant: It doesn't work for me. "Is eaten" works only in a present-tense narrative.

Comment: Well, can you come up with a memorable example that illustrates _both_ points in a single sentence? How about _"He died, and is attended by angels?"_ A present-tense narrative is exactly what I want here.

Comment: Yes, I think that one works, @P.E.Dant

Comment: It will please the ecclesiastics as well as the grammarians...

Answer (score 3):

This "buried" is the so-called past participle.   The past participle is a non-finite verb form.   The other non-finite forms are the infinitive and the gerund.   "Non-finite" means something like unbounded.   There are two characteristics common to non-finite forms in English.   They are not bound to a subject.   They are not bound by time.   Another way to express the same idea is to say that they do not form predicates and they do not have tense.

1) Is this "buried" an adjective?  No, not really.  It's a participle.  It is derived from a base verb.

Past participles express some result of the verbs from which they are formed.   For action verbs like "to bury", they represent a state that results from the action.   If I bury a treasure, the result is *a buried treasure*.   If I bury a treasure in my back yard, the result is *a treasure buried in my back yard*.

So, we start with the fact that participles can modify nouns in much the same way that adjectives can.   Even though "buried" is a verb and "happy" is an adjective, we can see the same grammatical relationships in "a buried treasure" and "a happy man".

When a participle modifies a noun in the manner of an adjective, it seems reasonable to call it "an adjective participle" or "a participial adjective".   Those are nothing but shorthand for "a participle doing an adjective's job".

2) Is this "buried" a participial adjective?   Sure, why not?

The argument of a copular (or linking) verb isn't called an object; it's called a complement.   Specifically, it's a subject (or subjective) complement.   There are two kinds of subject complements.   One kind is a different reference for the same referent, or a restatement of the subject.   We call that kind "nominative".   In the sentence "he is our teacher," "our teacher" is the predicate nominative subject complement.   The other kind of subject complement *modifies* the subject.   We call this kind "adjective".   In the sentence "he is happy", "happy" is the predicate adjective subject complement.

In the sentence "he is buried", we can see that "buried" still does the same job as an adjective like "happy".   We can call it a participial adjective serving as the predicate adjective subject complement.

3) Is this "buried" a predicate nominative?   No, it's a predicate adjective.

Even though the past participle "buried" doesn't take a subject, it is still a form of an action verb.   It implies an actor or agent.

This is the basis of passive-voice constructions.   This is the reason that passive-voice constructions exist and make sense.

The sentence "he is buried" implies at least one of the following:  Someone or something buries him.   Someone or something buried him.  Someone or something has buried him.   Since the participle "buried" has no tense, the grammar of "he is buried" cannot tell us the time of the act of burying.

There is no conflict between interpreting "is buried" as the copula with a participial predicate adjective subject complement and interpreting it as the passive voice, present tense, indefinite aspect and indicative mode construction.   The latter interpretation makes sense *because* the former interpretation carries the same semantics.   Those two interpretations result in the same meaning.

4) Is the clause in the passive voice?   Yep.

5) Does “he is buried” mean currently his body lies in a coffin covered with soil, or does it mean he has been buried by someone?

This "or" doesn't make sense to me.   If he *is buried*, if his present-tense state is the result of the action of burying, then some actor or agent for the action of burying is implied.   From the grammar alone, I can't tell whether the indefinite aspect represents a habitual state (i.e. he is usually buried because someone/thing often buries him) or merely a current state (e.g. he is now buried because someone/thing buried him earlier).   The mechanisms for knowing which of these possibilities makes sense in a given context is called *pragmatics*.

If we say "he was buried", that clearly references a *state* that existed in the past, and it can suggest that the state has ended or changed.   Obviously, it doesn't *require* that the state has changed.   A sentence like "He was buried there yesterday, so I assume he's still there" makes as much sense as "He was buried there, and I have no idea where he is now."

Comment: I disagree strongly with part of this. Except for the rather unusual use as present tense narrative, "He is buried ..." is not in the passive: the only verb is the copula, and "buried" is an adjective, not a verb (I don't deny that it is derived from a verb).

Comment: The disagreement is more than welcome if it can be clarified.  I don't see anything unusual about present tense narratives since casual conversation is littered with 'em.  I do see the same semantics in both "his wife buried him" and "he was buried by his wife".  I don't recall having ever seen a passive-voice construction that cannot also be construed as a copular structure with a participial phrase serving as the predicate adjectival.  I would find any counter-example or contraindicative test to be delightfully illuminating.