# The grammar of "be buried"

Tags: syntax, past-participles, parts-of-speech

What is the grammar of "be buried" in the following sentences?:

> The graves have all been found under the houses, right under the
>   floors. And it may be this burial custom that explains why the houses
>   were packed in so tightly without streets. I mean, you might think it
>   was for protection or something, but there has been no evidence found
>   yet of any violent attack that would indicate that kind of danger. It
>   maybe they wanted to live as near as possible to their ancestors’
>   graves and **be buried** near them themselves.

Comment: *maybe they wanted **to be** buried near them.* The second "infinitive marker" *(**to**)* is "deleted" because it's a "predictable" repeated element.

Comment: Related: [The ambiguous “he is buried”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/the-ambiguous-he-is-buried)

Comment: The same grammar as in this example: **I want to eat, play and be safe.** A single *to* is shared between three different verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What may be tripping you up is a missed space: I think the last sentence should read, "It **may be** they wanted to live as near as possible to their ancestors’ graves and be buried near them themselves." Meaning: "*The situation* may be [that] they wanted to ... be buried near [their ancestors' graves] themselves." (See the second sentence starting with "And it may be...".) As it stands this sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: It is purely grammatical. "They wanted to" is common for both the clauses as " the boy wanted to kiss the girl or be kissed by the girl."

Answer (score 2):

An infinitive ( to- infinitive) can be made passive in the following way.

- to+ be+ V³ of the root verb.

So people wanted to be buried near them( the ancestors) themselves.