# Is it "is buried" or "was buried" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Below is an example sentence from Collins English Dictionary. I wonder if there is a mistake in this sentence and if we should replace "is buried" with "was buried," as the first part of the sentence is past tense.

> He died a pauper and is buried in an unmarked grave.

Comment: Related: [The ambiguous “he is buried”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107449)

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer can't be "beaten".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Buried" is both the past participle of the verb *to bury* **and** an adjective to describe the state of being under the ground.

- You would say "he *was* buried" (verb) if you were referring to the *event of his burial*.
- You would say "he *is* buried" (adjective) if you wanted to refer to his current state or location under the ground.

Comment: You might also say, "he was buried in an unmarked grave until he was exhumed and moved to a new cememtary."

Comment: +1. This is a very common pattern in English; we can also say "The window is still broken. It was broken by a stray baseball" and "The door is still locked. It was locked with the master key" and "Your clothes are still packed away. They were packed away by the cleaning staff" and so on.