# What type of sentence is "The baby was born"?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech

Something like "The baby was born." or "The house was built." There's no person in the sentence actually doing the action. What do you call this type of sentence?

Comment: What makes you think such sentences should have a special name? To my knowledge there ain't no such nomenclature.

Comment: Are you just talking about a copular sentence?

Comment: The second is indisputably a sentence in the passive voice, with no agent specified (contrast 'The house was built by **Jack**').  // Some regard the verb 'be born' as English's semi-deponent verb.

Comment: Related: [The ambiguous "he is buried"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/the-ambiguous-he-is-buried)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *[1] The baby was born*.
>
> *[2] The house was built*.

These are both called **short passives**, the type of passive where a *by* phrase can usually be optionally omitted, cf. *The house was built in 1960* (*by a reputable local builder*).

In your first example with "born", no *by* phrase would be possible, cf. *"The baby was born by a Greek peasant".

Comment: The baby was born*e*  by a Greek peasant.  to bear or carry a baby.  In the sense of being born, it cannot be passive.

Comment: In BrE the past participle of "bear" is spelled "born" only in the passive, in the childbirth sense ("He was born in 1900" / "He was born rich"). Elsewhere it is "borne" ("It has borne fruit"). The OP used the verb "born", not "borne", thus indicating the former meaning was intended. Since the addition of a _by_ phase is infelicitous here, the OP's example can only be a 'short passive'.

Comment: A tree can bear fruit and a woman can bear a baby. In the past tense, this meaning is borne. "The baby was born on" (meaning come into the world) cannot be a passive because there can't be a agent like this: The baby was born by a mother. The form is some kind of defective.

Comment: @Lambie I've already explained why there can't be an agent (a _by_ phrase). Read my last comment again, particularly the bit about 'short' passive.  "The baby was born on 1 December" is a perfectly valid example of a passive clause.

Comment: It is not a passive like the others. It is defective as it cannot have an agent. Whereas: The house was built [by x] can. Ergo, they are completely different.

Comment: @Lambie The inability of a passive clause to have an agent does not diminish its status as a passive. It's simply called a 'short passive', one that has no agent (_by_ phrase). The term "short passive' applies generally to such passives; in most cases an agent ( _by_ phrase) is optional, but sometimes it is inadmissible, as is the case here.

Comment: @Lambie; @BillJ That's… uh… unbearable.

However stilted or unlikely, what could be wrong with "The baby was born by the mother"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Babies are born through birth canals. The fact of a "short passive" does not mean born by the mother is correct. The baby was born by C-section, ok. That said, I am not familiar with any passive, short or long, that cannot take a "by phrase". The verb to be born as far as I know is the only one that is like this,

Comment: @Lambie How "Babies are born…" might be a fine subject for a Question of its own, or for Chat and here, how does "The baby was born" differ from "The house was built"?

Is there any doubt that as a type of sentence, "The baby was born…" is 'passive'?

For more, ask older mid-wives or nurses, doctors or parents about the term 'delivered'. In the early part of my 60-plus years, what had been "the mother was delivered of a child" became "the mother delivered a child" which became "a/the child was delivered…"

Still "The baby was born" is simply a 'passive' sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is written in [passive voice](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/).