# How to tell whether ing forms are gerunds or participles

Tags: gerunds, participles, present-participles

So I looked up the meanings of the word "former" and the descriptions were as follows :

> 1. **Having** previously been a particular thing.
> 2. **Denoting** the first or first mentioned of two people or things.

I dont know whether *having* and *denoting* are gerunds or participles and although I can normally tell the difference sometimes its very difficult.

Examples of where its clear which one it is :

Gerund : Walking on the beach is fun.

Participle : Walking on the beach, I got sunburned because I forgot to use sunscreen.

Comment: Many modern grammars do not distinguish gerunds and present participles, simply calling the _-ing_ forms "gerund-participles" - it's simpler and better. So all your examples are best called "gerund-participial" clauses headed by the gerund-participle verbs "having", "denoting" and "walking".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this -ing form a gerund or a participle?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105696/is-this-ing-form-a-gerund-or-a-participle)

Answer (score -1):

A gerund is a word ending with `-ing` that functions as a noun.

Ex. I enjoy (the activity of) swimming).

Ex. Walking is healthy for you.

Ex. Sleeping is a pastime for some people.

Not a gerund: He is sleeping.