# What is the difference in the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

1. I confuse sometimes.
2. I get confused sometimes.

I know that the second one is in the passive form but is there any difference in the meaning of these two sentences. Are both grammatically correct?

Similarly,

1. A door closes.
2. A door is closed.

In this, I think both are grammatically correct but what is the meaning of the first sentence?
help

Comment: "I confuse sometimes" is not a sentence that has any meaning at all... You need to have an object... "I confuse [A] with/for [B] sometimes".

Answer (score 3):

The difference is between the active and passive voice.

> A door closes.

This is active. The **door** is the **subject**, and does the action: it **closes**.

> A door is closed.

This is passive. The **door** is the **object** of the action: it **is closed** (by someone or something). In this case, both are describing the same situation.

Likewise, your other two sentences are fine, but they mean different things. Let's start with the more easily understood one:

> I get confused sometimes.

This is passive. **I** is the **object** of the action: it **gets *(confused)*** sometimes.

> I confuse sometimes.

This is active, but it is not a good example. **I** is the **subject**, and does the action: it **confuses** (some other person or audience) sometimes. But a transitive verb requires an object; at least an implied object. To make it more understandable:

> I don't always explain things fully. I confuse *(others)* sometimes.

Comment: Except I don't know that anyone would actually say simply "I confuse sometimes"... they'd add an object... "I confuse people sometimes".

Comment: Agreed, it is not idiomatic; but it is grammatically correct, and might be said by a prankster, along the lines of *I kid sometimes.*

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert, but [consfused](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confused) looks like an adjective to me. So the it's in the active voice.

Comment: 1. [Dictionaries are bad sources for determining words' parts of speech](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part); and 2. Provided "Joe confused Mary" is a sentence, either Joe, or Mary, or confused is performing the function of a verb.

Comment: @Davo But this time, I trust my dictionary. "confused" is clearly an adjective because it's gradable and can be modified by [very](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105696/is-this-ing-form-a-gerund-or-a-participle/114533#114533)

Comment: Part of speech is really defined by how the word is used. I **heated** the water. The conversation became *very **heated***.

Comment: **Confused** as a verb: [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/confuse), [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/confuse),
 [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/confuse), [Verbix.com](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/confuse.html), [Reverso.net](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-confuse.html)...

Comment: @Davo According to OLD, confuse is a verb, but confus**ed** is an [adjective](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/confused). You might also enjoy reading [this](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/particip.htm).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59243/discussion-between-davo-and-user178049).

Comment: "Confused" can certainly be used an adjective. "Bob is a very confused person." "Confused" can be used as a verb. "Bob confused me when he talked about parts of speech." The question is which it is being used as here.

Answer (score -1):

Your first sentence is not grammatically correct

> I confuse sometimes.

In your next sentences

> A door closes.

a door is in the act of closing, changing from *open* to *close*.

> A door is closed.

a door is already in the state of being closed.

Comment: You don't explain why the first sentence is incorrect :(

Comment: It is incomplete, "I confuse sometimes *what*?" or you could say "I **am** confus**ed** sometimes."

Comment: Confuse is a transitive verb: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/confuse