# Could gerund be modified by an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gerunds

Is to possible to modify a gerund by using an adjective, especially when the gerund functions as noun? 
Such as this example:

> - Open shaming of anyone who spoke out discouraged responsible dissent.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105696/is-this-ing-form-a-gerund-or-a-participle/114533#114533

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62563/discussion-on-question-by-bavyan-yaldo-could-gerund-be-modified-by-an-adjective).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> Today's walking went well, we had a lot of fun.
>
> Today's arduous walking sucked, I never want to do it again.

Comment: Gerund is actually a verb form. In both sentences, the walking is a gerundial noun (noun derived from gerund).

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, you can modify it with an adjective.