# "drivers" or "driver's"?

Tags: possessives

> The Autopilot feature is designed to allow Teslas to cruise highways without **drivers** steering, braking or accelerating.

Source: Mosher, Alexandra, “[Tesla drivers play Jenga, sleep, using Autopilot in nerve-wracking videos](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/news/2016/07/01/drivers-play-jenga-sleep-using-tesla-autopilot-nerve-wracking-videos/86613484/),” *USA Today*, July 1, 2016

Is it possible to change *drivers* to *driver's* in the sentence above I found on the Internet?

Comment: The possessive there would not be idiomatic.   *We need to be secretive. It has to be done **without people finding out***.

Comment: No, because it means **without the drivers needing to steer,....” The **steering** does not belong to the driver

Comment: @RonaldSole You should write an answer along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

No. "Steering", "braking" and "accelerating" in this instance are all nouns for the *actions* carried out by the driver.

You see it is the *vehicle* that is accelerating (which is a verb), but the driver is carrying out an action which causes the vehicle to accelerate, and that is a noun because it is what we call that action. What the driver is actually doing is pressing pedals and turning a wheel, and of course the pressing and turning are verbs. But "accelerating" and "braking" are just what we call those actions carried out by the driver. So you would not speak of the driver possessing the accelerating, braking or whatever in this instance.

> The Autopilot feature is designed to allow Teslas to cruise highways without drivers steering, braking or accelerating.

If your intention is to make the sentence refer to a single driver you could change it to:

> The Autopilot feature is designed to allow Teslas to cruise highways without **the driver** steering, braking or accelerating.

Comment: Aren't "steering, braking and accelerating" simply verbs here?

Comment: And this is where you would use the possessive.  "The **drivers'** steering was affected by their consumption of alcohol."   Note the apostrophe goes after the 's' since drivers is plural.

Comment: @Bilkokuya No I don't believe so. The *vehicle* is accelerating (which is a verb), but the driver is carrying out an action which *causes* the vehicle to accelerate, and that is a *noun*. What the driver is *actually* doing is pressing (verb) pedals and turning (verb) a wheel. "Accelerating" and "braking" are just the names we call those actions.

Comment: @Astralbee See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/114533/). The first test you can perform is adding an object (nouns don't take direct objects; verbs do) to see whether the word at issue is a verb: *...without the driver steering **the car*** ← looks OK. So, it's a verb. But you can also use an adverb and an adjective in front of the word (as modifiers, adjectives go with nouns, while adverbs go with verbs): *...without the driver **carefully** steering* ← this one's alright; *...without the driver **careful** steering* ← nope.

Comment: @userr2684291 Why does the Oxford dictionary define "steering" as a noun? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steering

Comment: @Astralbee Who says it can't be? I only proved why it isn't in your example. Do you disagree with what I said?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is "drivers".  The " 's " is only used when the noun possesses / owns the item, with the exception of "it's".

The driver does not own or possess "steering, braking or accelerating".  They perform (or do) these actions.

This means that the fragment

```
drivers steering, braking or accelerating.
```

indicates multiple different drivers each performing some combination of "steering, braking or accelerating"