# Why is it v-ing after looking forward to?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I took an English grammar test and one question was:

> Chen's looking forward ... his new job next week.

There were four choices:  to starting / to start / starting / in starting.

My answer was "to start", because I knew the structure of "looking forward to" and because of the presence of "to", I used the infinitive.

But the answer was "to starting". Why "V-ing" is used in this case? Is there a rule for “to + v-ing”?

Comment: It would be better to say "I *took* a test of English grammar......The *choices* were..."

Comment: @Chowzen why? This sounds perfectly natural to me as written. We always say french test, maths test,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/grammatica-britannico/look-forward-to) gives the following explanation:

> Look forward to something means to be pleased or excited that it is going to happen. ***The ‘to’ in look forward to is a preposition, so we must follow it by a noun phrase or a verb in the -ing form:***
>
> - I’m looking forward to the holidays.
> - A:
>     Are you excited about your trip to South America?
> - B:
>     Yes, I’m looking forward to it.
> - We’re looking forward to going to Switzerland next month.
> - ***Not***: … looking forward to go to Switzerland …
>
> ***If the second verb has a different subject, we use the object form of the pronoun, not the subject form:***
>
> - We’re looking forward to him arriving next week.
>
>   - ***Not***: We’re looking forward to he arriving next week.
>
> ***We also use look forward to at the end of formal letters and formal emails*** to say that we hope to hear from someone or expect that something will happen. We use the present simple form:
>
> - I look forward to your reply.
> - We look forward to receiving payment for the services detailed above.

Answer (score 2):

We **look forward to** `something`, so you need to use the form of the verb which can also be understood as a noun, **starting**.

Comment: What's with this vague description "understood as a noun"? If it's a verb, it's a verb; if it's a noun, it's a noun. *Starting* is a verb in this sentence (not a noun): *Chen's looking forward to \*quick / quickly starting his new job*. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/114533/3395).

Comment: Can you please support your answer with some reference .

Comment: @userr2684291:  Why is being able to modify the -ing form with an adverb (*quickly starting*)  a "test" for its verbitudinality, whereas being the object of a preposition (*to having*, *in having*) or its ability to be preceded by a possessive pronoun (*their having*) are not tests for nounicality?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The first test is valid because prototypical verbs, unlike nouns, take adverbs as modifiers. The second test doesn't work because a gerund-participial clause can function as complement of a preposition. In your third proposed test, *their* can function as subject of the gerund-participial clause, which (just like your previous test) doesn't prove that the word at issue is a noun.

Comment: @user2684291: So your answer to OP would be "a gerund-participial clause can function as complement of a preposition" and you would leave it at that?  You wouldn't attempt to explain *why* a gerund-participial clause can be the complement of a preposition?

Answer (score 0):

Think at **'looking forward to'** as a replacement of **'excited about'** (even if the meaning is slightly different *)

Would you ever say the sentence below?!

> Chen is **'excited about'** to start his new job next week

In the above sentence the correct form is of course:

> Chen is **'excited about'** starting his new job next week

or

> Chen is **'looking forward to'** starting his new job next week

which is more natural.

[*] I came across [this article](https://englishwithkim.com/expect-looking-forward-excited-cant-wait/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20talk,better%20than%20%E2%80%9Cexcited%20about.%E2%80%9D) that explains when to use 'looking forward to' instead of 'excited about':

> "looking forward to is appropriate in most situations, so when in
> doubt, choose it."