# "A way with" + verb?

Tags: prepositions

When using the idiom "A way with", can I add a verb after it if it's a gerund?

For example,

- She has a way with playing cards.
- The school has a way with accepting only good candidates.

Comment: I'm a non-native speaker, but as a rule of thumb (only for my personal uses), I usually assume I can use gerunds in the places of 'something' that has been specified on the dictionary. I'm assuming gerund is basically a different kind of noun.

Comment: @GwangmuLee https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/114533/3395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gerund is a noun, not a verb. The expression "a way with" means "a talent for", and a noun following is required. I would hesitate to use 'accepting' in the second example, since acceptance is a matter of policy, and might prefer to use 'selecting' instead, since this would be something that the school has a flair for.

Comment: An *-ing* form isn't necessarily a noun. See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/114533/3395).

Comment: The definition of a 'gerund' is an -ing verb form functioning as a noun. When it is functioning as a verb, it is called a 'present participle'.