# What is the difference between social network and social networking?

Tags: grammar, questions, gerunds

I don't know when to use gerund. Someone told me that "networking" works as a noun, but "network" is a noun, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this -ing form a gerund or a participle?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105696/is-this-ing-form-a-gerund-or-a-participle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nouns ending in -ing refer to activities. Social networking is what one is doing when one is using a social network.